# Set auto height of title in onsenui

Tags: css, onsen-ui

I am using the following code to set the title with Onsen UI framework.

```
<ons-navigator
    title={{my_title}}  
    left-button-icon="fa fa-2x fa-angle-left"
    on-left-button-click="ons.slidingMenu.setAbovePage('xyz.html');"
    page="abc.html">
</ons-navigator>
```

But I am unable to see complete title when title is long in size.

Is there any way to set auto height of title bar by modifying anything in `unsenui.css` ( `onsen_navigator-title` ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please get the 'onsen_navigator-title' class here.
.onsen_navigator-title {
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

What do I need to modify?